Spring Security: How can I catch LDAP authentication exception when wrong credentials are sent to active directory?
Well, I've been trying to create an authentication filter with Spring Boot and Active Directory, but I'm encountering a loop of exceptions when I submit incorrect credentials.
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig {

    private static final String DOMAIN = "xxxxx.net";
    private static final String URL = "ldap://xxxxxx:389/";

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .cors(cors -> cors
                        .configurationSource(request -> {
                            CorsConfiguration corsConfiguration = new CorsConfiguration();
                            corsConfiguration.setAllowedOrigins(List.of("http://localhost:4200"));
                            corsConfiguration.setAllowedMethods(List.of("POST", "PUT", "GET", "DELETE", "OPTIONS"));
                            corsConfiguration.setAllowedHeaders(List.of("Authorization", "Content-Type"));
                            corsConfiguration.setAllowCredentials(true);
                            return corsConfiguration;
                        }))
                .authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize
                        .requestMatchers("auth/**").permitAll()
                        .anyRequest().authenticated())
                .formLogin(login -> login.permitAll())
        .sessionManagement(session ->
                        session.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.IF_REQUIRED));
        return http.build();
    }



    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth = http.getSharedObject(AuthenticationManagerBuilder.class);

        ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider adProvider =
                new ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider(DOMAIN, URL);
        adProvider.setConvertSubErrorCodesToExceptions(true);
        adProvider.setUseAuthenticationRequestCredentials(true);

        auth.authenticationProvider(adProvider);

        return auth.build();
    }
}

This is my code. It works fine when I send the correct credentials using the default login form provided by Spring Security. However, when I send incorrect credentials, the console shows an "infinite" loop of exceptions like this:
2024-06-22T01:56:14.121-05:00 DEBUG 19756 --- [waza] [nio-8080-exec-4] ctiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider : Authentication for fr@xxxxx.net failed:javax.naming.AuthenticationException: [LDAP: error code 49 - 80090308: LdapErr: DSID-0C090439, comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, data 52e, v4563 ]
2024-06-22T01:56:14.123-05:00  INFO 19756 --- [waza] [nio-8080-exec-4] ctiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider : Active Directory authentication failed: Supplied password was invalid
2024-06-22T01:56:14.136-05:00 DEBUG 19756 --- [waza] [nio-8080-exec-4] ctiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider : Authentication for fr@xxxxxx.net failed:javax.naming.AuthenticationException: [LDAP: error code 49 - 80090308: LdapErr: DSID-0C090439, comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, data 52e, v4563 ]
2024-06-22T01:56:14.136-05:00  INFO 19756 --- [waza] [nio-8080-exec-4] ctiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider : Active Directory authentication failed: Supplied password was invalid

a the end shows this
2024-06-22T01:56:19.888-05:00 ERROR 19756 --- [waza] [nio-8080-exec-4] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Filter execution threw an exception] with root cause

java.lang.StackOverflowError: null
    at java.base/java.net.URI$Parser.scan(URI.java:3141) ~[na:na]

Is there a way to catch this exception to prevent the stack overflow or end the action when this ldapErr happens?
Solution:
The following code catch the Exception
    @Bean
    SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable())
        .cors(cors -> cors.configurationSource(request -> {
            CorsConfiguration corsConfiguration = new CorsConfiguration();
            corsConfiguration.setAllowedOrigins(List.of("http://localhost:4200"));
            corsConfiguration.setAllowedMethods(List.of("POST", "PUT", "GET", "DELETE", "OPTIONS"));
            corsConfiguration.setAllowedHeaders(List.of("Authorization", "Content-Type"));
            corsConfiguration.setAllowCredentials(true);
            return corsConfiguration;
        }))
        .authorizeHttpRequests(
                authorize -> authorize.requestMatchers("auth/**").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated())
                .sessionManagement(session -> 
                    session.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.IF_REQUIRED));
        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth = http.getSharedObject(AuthenticationManagerBuilder.class);
        ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider adProvider = authProvider();
        auth.authenticationProvider(adProvider);
        return auth.build();
    }

    @Bean
    ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider authProvider() {
        ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider adlap = new ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider(DOMAIN, URL);
        adlap.setUseAuthenticationRequestCredentials(true);
        adlap.setConvertSubErrorCodesToExceptions(true);
        return adlap;
    }


The following code works for me and I'm not using HttpSecurity at all.
@Autowired
    private CustomLdapUserDetailsMapper customLdapUserDetailsMapper;

@Autowired
public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception
{

        auth.authenticationProvider(authProvider());        
}

    @Bean
    public ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider authProvider() {
        ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider adlap = new ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider(
                adLdapDomain, adLdapUrl, adLdapBase);
  /* adLdapDomain, adLdapUrl, adLdapBase should all be set to correct values */
        adlap.setUserDetailsContextMapper(customLdapUserDetailsMapper);
        adlap.setUseAuthenticationRequestCredentials(true);
        adlap.setConvertSubErrorCodesToExceptions(true);        
    
        return adlap;
    }   

In case a user has provided bad credentials, Spring boot will redirect to something like login?error so you can check for that (this is true provided that you don't have a custom login page in which case the actual url can be set to something different, e.g my-site?error)
Hope this helps.

Thank you for your help, I must use HttpSecurity, but your answer gave me an idea to solve this. I wil edit the answer with the solution.
